# how this works to accept multi-word string using scanf?

Tags: c

```
printf("enter the string");
    scanf("%[^\t\n]s",str);
```

//how the abv code works to accept multi word string without using gets and only using scanf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `[` Matches a nonempty sequence of
>   characters from the specified set
>   of  accepted  characters;  the next pointer must be a pointer to
>   char, and there must be enough room for all  the  characters in
>   the  string,  plus  a  terminating null byte.  The usual skip of
>   leading white space is suppressed. The string is to be made up
>   of  characters  in  (or  not  in)  a  particular set; the set is
>   defined by the characters between the open bracket `[`  character
>   and a close bracket `]` character.  The set excludes those
>   characters if the first character after the open bracket is a 
>   circumflex  (`^`).
>
> ...
>
> The string  ends  with the appearance of a character not in the (or, with a
>   circumflex, in) set or when the field width runs out.

(Linux `scanf(3)` manpage.)

So `scanf` reads up to the first character that is not a tab (`\t`) or newline (`\n`). It does read spaces.